How to import css modules in ESM project, on node.js during SSR
Im converting a web app from CJS to ESM.
The web app is bundled with webpack, but the first page load is rendered on the backend by node.js.
In the app I import CSS like this:
import style from './Body.module.css';

Currently (now that Ive switched to running ESM on node.js) that gives me this error:
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".css" for [retracted]/Body.module.css

Previously I was using ignore-styles to make sure node.js doesn't crash, but that's a Babel loader.
And apparently Babel doesnt work with ESM imports so I switched to TSX.
I tried node-hook but that's also a patch for require, it doesnt work for import statements.
Any recommendations how I can avoid this error when importing a .module.css file? Or any .css file?
Ideally I'd even get the same class names as webpack in node.js, but that might be a separate question.

ignore-styles only uses babel to publish a CJS version of their lib, and es modules can import CJS just fine, so maybe you’re saying something else. Also, that lib simply ignores the import and it would be very easy to write your own customization hook that registers a loader which checks the url the specifier resolves to in order to see if it ends in .css in which case you simply set the format to module and the source to an empty string. If the url from the resolved specifier has any other suffix then nextLoad(url).

Check out the transpilation example to get a better idea. However you should be able to continue using ignore-styles. What errors were you getting with that?
